# How to make a Cahn–Hilliard model GIF

Tags: image-processing, animation, simulation

[image]

The question derived from @Jason B 's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104978/21532).I wanna make it but don't how to do.But we can get some rule about the GIF

1. The change of the total pixel is very small.

`imagelist = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9np9.gif"]`

[image]

```
totalpixel = 
  ImageMeasurements[#, "Total"] & /@ imagelist // Total /@ # &;
ListLinePlot[Differences[totalpixel]/Most@totalpixel, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

2. A frame texture and the next frame roughly is the same.

So how to make this GIF by its first frame?

[image]

Comment: So those images came from this site: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation so you need to translate those equations describing a phase transition into a code

Comment: @JasonB Oh,It looks more difficult than what I think.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained and improve the title.  For instance, `Export["/tmp/foo.gif", Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/y9np9.gif"]]` seems to satisfy the requirements, accurately reproducing the gif, and it is quite the easiest way.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry my poor English,I have changed some place as your advice just now.If there are other flaw you think in my expression,help to improve it.I will be so thankful.

Comment: @yode I thought you wanted an implementation of the Cahn-Hilliard model, and I thought you should add  a brief description of what it is as a guide to answerers and other readers of the Q&A.  It seems (now, to me) that you're after anything that looks similar to the animation, in which case the question seems ok now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am delighted by this problem mostly because I was not aware of the underlying physical model of phase separation (the [Cahn–Hilliard equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation))!

Anyway, here is an approximation of a somewhat similar behavior to start the discussion:

```
NestList[
    Sharpen@Threshold[GaussianFilter[#, 2], {"Hard", {"BlackFraction", 0.1}}] &, 
    img, 50
];

ListAnimate[%]
```

[image: Imgur]

I am looking forward to something better from the image processing experts!

---

Here is an alternative method. It is still based on image processing, but it uses `CommonestFilter` instead of the combination of operations used before. It is interesting to note that these situations almost always reach a steady state in relatively few iterations (hence the use of `FixedPointList` rather than `NestList` here.

```
SeedRandom[20160216]
img = Image@RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {256, 256}];
list = FixedPointList[Binarize[CommonestFilter[#, 3], 0.5] &, img, 2000];
```

[image: Results of CommonestFilter]

Comment: Very neat that you can capture the overall effect with image transformations, I never would have thought to try this route.  +1

Comment: Concern the concision and ingeniousness of your second method.I firm accepted your answer in spite of it may not be accurately in accordance with the theorem of  [Cahn–Hilliard equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation) .And thanks for your help.

Comment: @yode Thank you! I'm glad you liked it: It was fun to play with.

Answer (score 14):

Taken from the Matlab code here http://www.math.utah.edu/~eyre/computing/matlab-intro/ch.txt with slight modifications:

```
m = n = 256;
delx = 1/(m - 1);
delx2 = delx^2;
x = Range[0, 1, delx];

delt = 0.00000001;
ntmax = 250;

epsilon = 0.01;
eps2 = epsilon^2;

a = 2;

lam1 = delt/delx2;
lam2 = eps2*lam1/delx2;

leig = Transpose@Table[2 Cos[π Range[0., n - 1]/(n - 1)] - 2, {m}] + 
 Table[2 Cos[π Range[0., m - 1]/(m - 1)] - 2, {n}];

cheig = 1 - (a*lam1*leig) + (lam2*leig^2);

seig = lam1*leig;

u = RandomReal[{-.5, .5}, {n, m}];
hatu = FourierDCT[u];

t = 0.;
Monitor[
 While[t < ntmax*delt,
  t += delt;
  hatu = (hatu + seig*FourierDCT[u^3 - (1 + a)*u])/cheig;
  u = FourierDCT[hatu];
  ], ArrayPlot[Sign[u - Mean[u]] + 1, PixelConstrained -> 1]]
ArrayPlot[Sign[u - Mean[u]] + 1, PixelConstrained -> 1]
```

[image: animation]

After 10000 time steps:

[image: final image]

Comment: This is the best answer so far IMO, but the code gives a lot of errors and doesn't return a result on my version 10.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: @thedude it seems I accidentaly forgot to copy two lines of code so `eps2` was not defined. Can you try now?

Comment: Now it works fine, quite fast too.

Comment: @shrx +1, it's always cool to see interesting physics simulated with Mathematica!

Answer (score 11):

Here's a version using `CellularAutomaton` to simulate the [Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) (with Glauber dynamics), which can be viewed as a lattice version of the Cahn–Hilliard equation. It's not quite as smooth as the GIF, but it can probably be improved with some tweaks:

```
With[{L = 100, T = 0.1, t = 100, dt = 10, r = 0.1},
    ArrayPlot[#, ColorRules -> {-1 -> Black, 1 -> White}, PixelConstrained -> True] & /@
    CellularAutomaton[
        {
            ( {{_, a_, _},{d_, x_, b_},{_, c_, _}} ) :> 
                If[RandomReal[] < r/(E^(2/T x (a + b + c + d)) + 1), -x, x]
        },
        RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {L, L}],
        {{0, t, dt}}]
] // ListAnimate
```

[image: animation]

Comment: Hey Stephen, I took the liberty of adding an animation generated from your code. It's a very cool use of a cellular automaton! (+1)

Comment: I really like this, well done!

Answer (score 5):

```
init = RandomReal[1, {200, 200}];
alpha = -1; beta = -1; gamma = 1; s = 50;

replenish[n_] := RandomReal[1, {n}]
step[a_] := 
  MapThread[
   Prepend, {MapThread[
     Append, {Insert[
       Table[a[[i, j]] + 
         alpha (a[[i, j + 1]] - a[[i, j]] + a[[i, j - 1]]) + 
         beta (a[[i + 1, j + 1]] + a[[i - 1, j + 1]] + 
            a[[i + 1, j - 1]] + a[[i - 1, j - 1]] - a[[i, j]]) + 
         gamma (a[[i + 1, j]] + a[[i - 1, j]] - a[[i, j]]), {i, 2, 
         Length@a - 1}, {j, 2, Length@First@a - 1}], 
       replenish[Length@a - 2], {{-1}, {1}}], replenish[Length@a]}], 
    replenish[Length@a]}];
Do[Subscript[mat, 1] = init; 
 Subscript[mat, i] = step[Subscript[mat, i - 1]];, {i, 2, s}]
ListAnimate[
 Table[ReliefPlot[Subscript[mat, i], ColorFunction -> GrayLevel], {i, 
   s}]]
```

[image]

[image]

---

Upon vaxquis's remark in the comments, I am posting a much more concise version of the code. All credit goes to him.

```
conv = {{γ, α, γ}, {β, 1-α-β-γ, β}, {γ, α, γ}}; 
α = 1; β = -1; γ = -1; 

list = ListConvolve[conv, RandomReal[1, {200, 200}], 2]; 
lists={list}; 
For[i=0, i<50, i++,
  list = ListConvolve[conv, list, 2]; 
  AppendTo[lists, list];
]; 

ListAnimate[ReliefPlot[#, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]& /@ lists]
```

---

J.M. suggested the use of NestList[] instead of For[] in the code above:

```
conv = {{γ, α, γ}, {β, 1-α-β-γ, β}, {γ, α, γ}}; 
α = 1; β = -1; γ = -1; 
ListAnimate[
 ReliefPlot[#, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel] & /@ 
  NestList[ListConvolve[conv, #, 2] &, 
   ListConvolve[conv, RandomReal[1, {200, 200}], 2], 50]]
```

This decreases the computation time from about 2.96 to 2.82 seconds on my machine, averaged over 10 trials.

Comment: Where are from the second gif?

Comment: alpha=-1; beta=1; gamma=-1

Comment: The improvement is so obvious that I wanna give second upvote.

Comment: Could've used `NestList[]` instead of a loop: `ListAnimate[ReliefPlot[#, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel] & /@ NestList[ListConvolve[conv, #, 2] &, ListConvolve[conv, RandomReal[1, {200, 200}], 2], 50]]`.

Comment: @J.M. I can't try it right now, does it make a noticeable performance change?

Comment: On my machine, yes.

Comment: I'm deeply moving about your changes over and over again.But I can only accepted one answer.Very sorry to what you pay for.